# Error using Server.Execute outside of controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to run `Server.Execute` outside of the controller from an external function.  I have tried passing numerous types of objects trying to get this to work, but each time I get an error saying `Error: Error executing child request for [url]`

This is how my code looks inside of the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Exec(){
    var http = HttpContext; //<- doesn't work
    http = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context; //<- doesn't work

    return execMethodAsync(http);
}
```

Then in another class the code is:

```
public async Task execMethodAsync(HttpContext context){
   context.Server.Execute("/myurl"); // <-- Throws error
}
```

I have tried passing a number of object types to this method but still get this error.

I tried passing `HttpContext`, `HttpContext.CurrentHandler`, `ControllerContext.HttpContext` and even some other ones, but still get this error.  It seems nearly impossible to run `Server.Execute()` outside of the controller.  Can someone please help with executing `Server.Execute` outside of the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things could be causing this, have you tried

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("yourpage.aspx");
```

Comment: I don't have a `.Current` context. I am trying to pass context to an external model

Comment: Right ok, perhaps you have a HttpHandler in the external app causing this, a similar issue to this maybe: 

http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/Error_executing_child_request.asp